# CMD Prompt: Program shutting down when starting 2 programs with arguments

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to run a powershell command and a program called Psuite simultaneously in a batch file.

I searched through S.O. and I found an interesting command: Call :RunProgramAsync, but I researched it and can't make it work at all.

Here are the commands I want to execute. Currently, it will run the first for a second, shut it off. I want it to run the first then the second while keeping the first on. Each command works on its own.

Here is what I want to run:

```
cd C:\ASD\scripts
start PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%~dpn0.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"


cd C:\psuitent\tests
start psuite -l200 -EGB5 $c:\psuitent\swt\hpsmtsas.swt
```

Can someone help me? I have been searching all over and can't find a solution.

Comment: How about `""` -> `\"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use `start` it opens up a new window, so this might be causing an issue with `cd`, try something like this instead:

```
start "" /d "C:\ASD\scripts" PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%~dpn0.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"
start "" /d "C:\psuitent\tests" psuite -l200 -EGB5 $c:\psuitent\swt\hpsmtsas.swt
```

Hope this helps!

Source: [Running multiple commands simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136210/running-multiple-commands-simultaneously)

Comment: That actually did work. It was in combination with my file argument in the powershell file execution as it was set to the same filename as the batch file name. Thank you!

Comment: Are you getting error messages or is it running one after another?

Comment: Also it appears that the first line is starting Powershell which starts a new Powershell process to run the script, which is redundant. So you can try eliminating that and see if it helps.